# how to use fluentd regexp when meet the nginx bad request

Tags: regex, fluentd

I use the `fluentd` to replace the `logstash`, I use `in-tail` plugin to tail the `nginx access` log, the access log's format is like:

```
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request '
'"$status" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
'"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" $request_time';
```

the `fluentd` conf is like

```
format /^(?<host>\S+)\s-\s(?<user>\S+)\s\[(?<time>[^\]]*)\]\s(?<method>\S+)\s(?<url>\S+)\s(?<http_version>\S+)\s"(?<status>[^\"]+)"\s(?<bytes>\d+)\s"(?<rfc>[^\"]+)"\s"(?<agent>[^\"]+)"\s"(?<x_forward>[^\"]+)"\s(?<time_spent>\S+).*$/
```

it works fine when the request is correct, but it meet error when the request is bad, just like following:

```
172.31.33.157 - - [08/May/2017:16:30:20 +0800] - "400" 0 "-" "-" "-" 0.000
```

the bad request miss the `method` and `rfc` field，so the `fluentd` runs wrong. how can I modify the `format` so that I don't care about whether the request is bad or correct?

any answers will be appreciated

run into another scenario， the `agent` or `rfc` filed is none, it runs error. just like

```
172.31.44.196 - - [08/May/2017:18:47:31 +0800] GET /click?mb_pl=ios&version=1.1 HTTP/1.1 "302" 5 "-" "" "100.38.38.149, 54.224.136.60" 0.004
```

or

```
172.31.44.196 - - [08/May/2017:18:47:31 +0800] GET /click?mb_pl=ios&version=1.1 HTTP/1.1 "302" 5 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14E304" "100.38.38.149, 54.224.136.60" 0.004
```

how to solve this scenario?

Comment: What does a correct request look like?

Comment: 172.31.44.196 - - [08/May/2017:18:47:31 +0800] GET /click?mb_pl=ios&version=1.1 HTTP/1.1 "302" 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14E304" "100.38.38.149, 54.224.136.60" 0.004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wrap the parts of the pattern that are optional within *optional non-capturing groups*, `(?:...)?`:

```
^(?<host>\S+)\s-\s(?<user>\S+)\s\[(?<time>[^\]]*)\](?:\s(?<method>\S+))?(?:\s(?<url>\S+))?\s(?<http_version>\S+)\s"(?<status>[^\"]+)"\s(?<bytes>\d+)(?:\s"(?<rfc>[^\"]+)")?\s"(?<agent>[^\"]+)"\s"(?<x_forward>[^\"]+)"\s(?<time_spent>\S+).*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yqvzkb/2)

Here, I wrapped the following parts:

```
(?:\s(?<method>\S+))?
(?:\s(?<url>\S+))?
(?:\s"(?<rfc>[^\"]+)")?
```

That means, the whole subpattern sequences will be optiona, a whitespace and the named capture group patterns.

Note: when you have more optional fields, you may find yourself in a situation when the pattern groups start matching unwanted parts of the input that belong to other groups. In that case, make sure you **restrict the generic patterns** and use optional patterns: replace `+` with `*` to match 0 or more occurrences rather than 1 or more, use optional groups as show above, and make sure you only match the characters/patterns that are expected.

See an enhanced pattern below:

```
^(?<host>\S+)\s-\s(?<user>\S+)\s\[(?<time>[^\]]*)\](?:\s(?<method>\w+))?(?:\s(?<url>\/\S+))?\s(?<http_version>\S+)\s"(?<status>\d+)"\s(?<bytes>\d+)(?:\s"(?<rfc>[^\"]*)")?(?:\s"(?<agent>[^\"]*)")?\s"(?<x_forward>[^\"]*)"\s(?<time_spent>[\d.]+).*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yqvzkb/3).

Some POIs here:

- `(?<method>\w+))?` - here, we only match word chars (`\S` > `\w`, you may even consider using `[A-Z]`)
- `(?:\s(?<url>\/\S+))?` - added `/` since your URLs start with `/`
- `(?<status>\d+)` - `\S` changed to `\d` (since the status code consists of digits only)
- `(?<rfc>[^\"]*)")?` - the `+` is changed to `*` (the value can be empty)
- `(?:\s"(?<agent>[^\"]*)")?` - same here as with `rfc`
- `\s"(?<x_forward>[^\"]*)"` - same as above
- `(?<time_spent>[\d.]+` - the time_spent value only contains digits and dots.

Comment: If you have other optional fields try wrapping the `\s`+`the subpattern` with the optional non-capturing group.